# A non-Banach space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces

> Find, with proof, a compact set $K$ and a Banach space $W$ such that $C(K,W)$ equipped with the sup norm (i.e. $\|f\|_\infty = \sup\{\|f(x)\|_W : x \in K\}$) the set of continuous functions from $K$ to $W$ is not a Banach space.

Using a similar proof to the proof that $C([0,1]) = C([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ is a Banach space, it can be shown that $C([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ for any $a<b\in\mathbb{R}$ is a Banach space. However, I'm unsure how to find the given set $K$ and Banach space $W$. I think it might have something to do with uniform continuity of functions not "behaving" as well in certain Banach spaces as in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Depending on the used conventions you might be able to say that $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_{\infty}$ does not define a norm on $C(\varnothing, W)$. But with the more standard conventions it does.

Comment: why do you think that it is true? What is your definition of compact?

Comment: I'd say the claim is false. If we avoid the issue mentioned by Daniel Fischer, the space of bounded functions $(B(S,W),\lVert\bullet\rVert_\infty)$ is Banach if and only if either $X=\emptyset$ or $W$ is Banach, and this fact is unrelated to having a topology on $S$. The fact that $CB((X,\tau),W)$ is a closed subspace of $(B(X,W),\lVert\bullet\rVert_\infty)$ is universal as well, and for compact $X$ it holds $CB(X,W)=C(X,W)$ for all metric spaces $W$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition $K$ compact and $W$ Banach always makes $C(K,W)$ Banach.

The fact that $K$ is compact guarantees that $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is a norm.

Let $\{f_n\}\subset C(K,W)$ be a Cauchy sequence. For each $k\in K$, we have $$\|f_n(k)-f_m(k)\|=\|(f_n-f_m)(k)\|\leq\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty,$$
so $\{f_n(k)\}$ is Cauchy in $W$. As $W$ is Banach, there exists $f(k)=\lim_nf_n(k)\in W$. Now fix $\varepsilon>0$. Take $n_0$ such that $\|f_n-f_m\|<\varepsilon$ when $n,m>n_0$. For $n,m>n_0$,
$$
\|f_n(k)-f(k)\|\leq\|f_n(k)-f_{m}(k)\|+\|f_{n_0}(k)-f(k)\|\leq \varepsilon +\|f_{m}(k)-f(k)\|.
$$
As this holds for any $m$, we obtain $\|f_n(k)-f(k)|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>n_0$, and so the convergence is uniform. This makes $f$ continuous: indeed, fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists $n$ such that $\|f_n-f\|<\varepsilon/3$. Let $\delta>0$ such that $\|f_n(k)-f_n(h)\|<\varepsilon/3$ when $\|k-h\|<\delta$; then
$$
\|f(k)-f(h)\|\leq\|f(k)-f_n(k)\|+\|f_n(k)-f_n(h)\|+\|f_n(h)-f(h)\|\leq\frac\varepsilon3+\frac\varepsilon3+\frac\varepsilon3=\varepsilon
$$
and $f$ is continuous. So $C(K,W)$ is Banach.